# How to combine Ubuntu/Debian kernel config into single config

Tags: ubuntu, debian, kernel

Ubuntu has split up the kernel configs in the `debian.master/config/` directory like this:

```
linux-3.2.0/debian.master/config % tree
.
├── amd64
│   ├── config.common.amd64
│   ├── config.flavour.generic
│   └── config.flavour.virtual
├── armel
│   ├──...
├── config.common.ports
├── config.common.ubuntu
├── enforce
├── i386
│   ├── ...
├── ...
```

I would like to create a **single** config for building an amd64 kernel.

What is the best way to combine these configs? Do I just concatenate them?

(Note that I just want to create the config, not actually build the kernel - of course I want to do that later, but that is not part of the question).

Comment: Debian seem to like doing this, it's horrendous. I think you can just concatenate them. It may also be possible to find the current config in /proc/config.gz or in /boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run these:

```
debian/rules debian/control
debian/rules genconfigs
```

You'll find the output in the `CONFIGS` directory.

This command is broadly equivalent and writes directly to `.config` (unless you use the `-o builddir` flag):

```
scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh \
  debian.master/config/config.common.ubuntu \
  debian.master/config/amd64/config.common.amd64 \
  debian.master/config/amd64/config.flavour.generic
```

You can also run `debian/rules editconfigs` for menu-based editing, or edit the files in `CONFIGS` manually and run `debian/rules updateconfigs`.

More info on the Ubuntu Wiki: [Kernel/Compile](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) and [Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel).